# Tournament arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c

Let's say I have a tournament of 2^k people (k from user input). Each person is given a number from range <0;2×10^7> (from user input). There will be k rounds. In the first round, the people next to each other will "fight", and the outcome will be decided by whether the abs(assigned_num_1 - assigned_num_2) is divisible by 2 or not (if it is then the first person wins, if not then the second person wins). The winner will go to the next round and the process will repeat itself until the last round is concluded. Now I need to print out exactly how many "fights" has each person won.

Example:

k = 2 so there is 4 people in total. Their numbers are 6 2 3 4.

6 and 2 fight, person with 6 wins. 3 and 4 fight, person with 4 wins. 6 and 4 fight, person with 6 wins. So the output is 2 0 0 1.

My first thought was making an array which's size changes based on the round we're in but this doesn't seem possible in C (at least to my limited knowledge). Any other solutions that come to mind seem overly complicated for such a simple-sounding problem. Does anyone have better ideas? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: X+half of that + half of that + ... + 1 sums to 2*X-1, so you could do this with one 2^(k+1) array.

Comment: *My first thought was making an array which's size changes*. If the memory was obtained from `malloc()` you can change its size with `realloc()`.

Comment: The array with the win counts needs to be large enough for all the original players. You can't shrink it each round, because you need to preserve the counts from the previous rounds.

Comment: first response: this WILL work but I'll be using up a bit more space than is entirely necessary I suppose
:::second response: I'm not well-versed in using malloc and realloc so I suppose I'll have to read more about that but thanks
:::third response: I wasn't talking about shrinking the array with their points, but the array that each assigned number is in. I mean I don't need the assigned numbers of players who lost anymore.

Comment: @JakubŁaszewski, you don't need to store the numbers assigned to people who have lost, but you do need somehow to track the index into the score array to which each element of the number array corresponds.  Simplest would be to just maintain the same indices in both arrays.  There probably is not much advantage to shrinking the numbers array, even if that produces some space savings, because even without, the highest memory requirement is already passed by the time the opportunity to reduce usage arrives.

Comment: I'd make one array of length 2^k. Each element holding a struct that contains their number and the number of wins. In each round `i` (1 <= i <= k) you can determine who is still in the tournament by looking at the number of wins. If it's `i-1` he won all previous fights, if it's `< i-1` he lost at least one, thus is already out. Then you iterate over the array, let the remaining neighbours "fight" and increase the winning count respectivily. After `k` rounds you only have one person left, the winner of the tournament, and for all others you have the number of their respective wins.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem using a straightforward approach without dynamically changing the size of an array. Here's a simplified way to achieve your goal:

Read the values of k and the assigned numbers of people into an array.

Initialize an array to keep track of the number of fights won for each person, initially set to zero.

Simulate each round, iterating k times:

a. For each pair of neighbors (i and i+1), calculate the outcome based on the divisibility of abs(assigned_num[i] - assigned_num[i+1]).

b. If the outcome is in favor of the first person (divisible by 2), increment the number of fights won for the i-th person.

Repeat the rounds until you have conducted k rounds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);

    int n = (int)pow(2, k);
    int assigned_num[n];
    int fights_won[n];

    // Read assigned numbers from user input
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &assigned_num[i]);
        fights_won[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int round = 0; round < k; round++) {
        int step = (int)pow(2, round + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += step) {
            for (int j = i; j < i + step / 2; j++) {
                int diff = abs(assigned_num[j] - assigned_num[j + step / 2]);
                if (diff % 2 == 0) {
                    fights_won[j]++;
                } else {
                    fights_won[j + step / 2]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the number of fights won by each person
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", fights_won[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code should calculate and print the number of fights won by each person based on the given rules for k rounds.

Comment: In every round you start with `i = 0` and therefore `j = 0`. Later you use `assigned_num[j]`. And with `j == 0` you therefore will include (for instance) the element at index `0` in every round. That's not the desired behaviour, because if a "fighter" lost in one round it should not be considered in the future rounds anymore

Comment: Tryit with for instance an inputarray of `1, 2, 4, 5, 7,9,10,12`. The result will be `1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2`. This is wrong for (at least) two reasons: 1. There should be at least one element having won 3 fights (ie in all rounds). The very first element (`1`) must lose its first battle (because `1+ 2 = 3`, thus the second element of this pair wins the battle), thus must not participate in the following rounds anymore. How can it have a won battle?